# HTTP Status 503 Error while migrating Tomcat 6 to glassfish v2.1

Tags: jsf, exception, jsf-2, primefaces, http-status-code-503

I am using Prime faces in my application.
I have specification to migrate Tomcat server(6) to Glass fish(v2.1)
I have done it in net beans.

But I am getting HTTP Status 503 Error while running project.
(Working fine while using tomcat 6)

Getting This in console

```
Initializing Mojarra (1.2_13-b01-FCS) for context '/Prime'
WebModule[/Prime]PWC1275: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '2.0' is not
facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[1.2]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.
```

Why i am getting this error and please give me a solution for this.

Thank You.

Comment: Is the server being initialized properly? Do you have any errors in its log?

Comment: Yes. I have edited the question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish v2 ships as being a full fledged Java EE 5 container with JSF 1.2 bundled. Your webapp is apparently a JSF 2.0 based one which has JSF 2.0 libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib`. This will of course conflict with Glassfish's own JSF 1.2 librares with errors like this. Your specific error is caused by having `<faces-config version="2.0">` which isn't supported by JSF 1.2.

Whilst backwards compatible with Java EE 5, JSF 2.0 is part of Java EE 6 and thus by default only bundled in Glassfish v3 and so on. That it works in Tomcat is obviously because Tomcat as being a barebones JSP/Servlet container doesn't ship with JSF bundled, but only with JSP/Servlet. So there would be no potential version conflicts with JSF in Tomcat.

You need to tell Glassfish that it should not use its own bundled JSF, but instead the webapp bundled JSF. You can do that by adding the following entries to `<sub-web-app>` of `/WEB-INF/sun-web.xml` file:

```
<class-loader delegate="false"/>
<property name="useBundledJsf" value="true"/>
```

If you don't have this file, you can find a sample at the bottom of this [Glassfish v2.1.1 deployment guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0184/beaql/index.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC '-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD 
   Application Server 9.0 Servlet 2.5//EN' 
   'http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_2_5-0.dtd'>
<sun-web-app>
   <!-- Your config here -->
</sun-web-app>
```

Comment: Hi BalusC,
i have done the same as 
<class-loader delegate="false"/>
<property name="useBundledJsf" value="true"/>
but it sill loading jsf1.2 not jsf 2.1
Initializing Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_04-b22-p05) for context '/test1'

Comment: Which Glassfish v2 version exactly are you using? In very early versions they used an unintuitive property name `useMyFaces` which was shortly later renamed to `useBundledJsf`. Try it with `<property name="useMyFaces" value="true"/>` instead.

Comment: We are using GlassFish v2.1 and PrimeFaces 3.4.2

Comment: <property name="useMyFaces" value="true"/>
Tried with this also.
Its not working

Comment: Well, apparently the `sun-web.xml` is not in proper location or not properly redeployed. Contact the serveradmin if you're unsure.